# Polymer firebase messaging error

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-cloud-messaging

Ive been following rob dodson's Firebase messaging tutorial and I am getting this error

> Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

Why am I getting this error?

I have the firebase-messaging-sw.js file and I have the necessary dependencies imported to it

Comment: If you check the network or sources tab of your browser's developer tools, you will see that it retrieves `firebase-messaging-sw.js`. View the actual content that is returned there, since most likely it's an HTML error page.

Comment: I've solved it already.. Im using polymer starter kit and I hadn't added the firebase messaging js file in the static globs. So it wasn't being added as a dependency in the build. I added it and its all good. Thanks though

Comment: Good to hear Tevin!